# How can I load a textfile with many rows?

Tags: c#, xna

I have some textfiles which look similar to the following one:

```
0,75;1,20;true;4,50;4,30;3,30;false
0,75;1,20;true;4,50;4,30;4,30;true
```

I load the textfile like this:

```
private const string filename = "Data.txt";
string[] strs;
public void LoadTextfile()
    {
        System.IO.Stream stream = TitleContainer.OpenStream(filename);
        System.IO.StreamReader reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(stream);       
        strs = reader.ReadLine().Split(';');
        game1.StatsList.Add(new Containerclass.StatsContainer(float.Parse(strs[0], culture), float.Parse(strs[1], culture), bool.Parse(strs[2]), float.Parse(strs[3], culture), float.Parse(strs[4], culture), float.Parse(strs[5], culture), bool.Parse(strs[6])));        
        strs = reader.ReadLine().Split(';');
        game1.StatsList.Add(new Containerclass.StatsContainer(float.Parse(strs[0], culture), float.Parse(strs[1], culture), bool.Parse(strs[2]), float.Parse(strs[3], culture), float.Parse(strs[4], culture), float.Parse(strs[5], culture), bool.Parse(strs[6])));
```

But my textfiles have much more entries(more than 100) than the textfile above. In addition, I don't know the number of rows of any textfile. Maybe one textfile has 110 rows, the second textfile 150 rows, etc.
Is it possible to load everything with a loop if I don't know the number of rows? Which loop should I use to load the entire textfile? I know that I can not use a for-loop because I don't know how much rows the textfile has, is it possible to load it with another loop? Or is it not possible to load an entire textfile with one loop?

Comment: Load it as CSV to DataSet.

Comment: Have you heard of a `while` loop?

Comment: This page has an example that should get you going: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.readline%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: 100 isn't much.  Just read them into a List or array

Comment: @adv12 He's already using that...

Comment: @BradleyDotNET, oops yup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that a `for` loop can be run without explicitly knowing the number of elements to iterate over - the central statement can be *any* conditional evaluating to a `bool`, not just `i < number`

```
using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
{
    for(string line = reader.ReadLine();
        reader.EndOfFile == false;
        line = reader.ReadLine())
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

Using `File.ReadLines` will also allow you to iterate over each line using a `foreach` -

```
foreach(string line in File.ReadLines(filename))
{
    //...
}
```

Being a little more explicit, you can also use [`StreamReader.ReadToEnd`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.readtoend%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and `Splt` the results

```
foreach(var line in new StreamReader(stream)
    .ReadToEnd()
    .Split(new [] {"\r\n" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
{
    //...
}
```

Comment: While true, that doesn't match well with the `for` semantic. A `while` is a better choice.

Comment: One would normally also wrap reader in `using` statement which this doesn't really allow for. Nothing is going to get disposed unless called explicitly inside a try/finally

Comment: I've integrated such comments into my answer

Answer (score 4):

`File.ReadLines(string path)` is really nice

```
string[] lines = File.ReadLines("filename.txt").ToArray();
```

---

If you really want to get fancy, you can try some linq

```
game1.StatsList = File.ReadLines("Data.txt")
    .Select(s => 
    {
        var strs = s.Split(';');
        return new Containerclass.StatsContainer(float.Parse(strs[0], culture), float.Parse(strs[1], culture), bool.Parse(strs[2]), float.Parse(strs[3], culture), float.Parse(strs[4], culture), float.Parse(strs[5], culture), bool.Parse(strs[6]));
    })
    .ToList();
```

Comment: ... provided the file is short enough to be read into memory all at once.

Comment: @adv12 the user said that there are around 110 rows and 150 rows.  that should be plenty short

Comment: Note `File.ReadLines` returns an Enumerable of strings, and won't overload a memory buffer anyway